# How to get appointment with EWS by uniqueId

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices, appointment

I create appointment using EWS without problem. I save the uniqueId like this

```
Dim rdvEncours As DevisRdv = GetRdv(ConnectedUser,LesDatas) 
Appointment.Save(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, rdvEncours.Collaborateur.Mail))
rdvEncours.ExchangeId = Appointment.Id.UniqueId
LesDatas.SaveChange();
```

After I want to delete it. I've a working function based on Title,Day,hour but It's not completly safe. Then I want use my UniqueId
Then I create this function

```
Public Function FindAppointment(Service As ExchangeService, UnikId As String) As Appointment
    Dim CalendarFolder As CalendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(Service, New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, ml), New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.TotalCount))

    ' Set the number of items to the smaller of the number of items in the Contacts folder Or 1000.
    Dim numItems As Integer = If(CalendarFolder.TotalCount < 1000, CalendarFolder.TotalCount, 1000)

    ' Instantiate the item view with the number of items to retrieve from the contacts folder.
    ' To keep the request smaller, send only the display name.
    Dim View As ItemView = New ItemView(numItems) With {.PropertySet = New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Start)}

    ' Create a searchfilter to check the subject of the tasks.
    Dim searchFilter As SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection = New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection From {New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.Id, UnikId)}

    ' Retrieve the items in the Calendar folder with the properties you selected.
    Dim taskItems = Service.FindItems(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, ml), searchFilter, View)

    If taskItems.Count = 1 AndAlso TypeOf taskItems.Items(0) Is Appointment Then
        Return taskItems.Items(0)
        HelperJournal.WriteEntry("Find Rdv by id") 'TODO:A mettre ne commentaire quand vérifier
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

I call it like this

```
Dim FoundTask As Appointment = FindAppointment(ConnectToExchange(), rdvEncours.ExchangeId)
If (FoundTask IsNot Nothing) Then FoundTask.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete)
```

But an error occured on FindAppointment

> Message:La valeur spécifiée est non valide pour la propriété.
>   Exception:Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: La valeur spécifiée est non valide pour la propriété.
>      à Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
>      à Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.ThrowIfNecessary()
>      à Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>      à Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
>      à Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
>      à Maximus.HelperAgenda.FindAppointment(ExchangeService Service, String UnikId) dans XXX\HelperAgenda.vb:ligne 50
>      à Maximus.VisuDevis.PoseInter(SetDevisRDV MesDonnees) dans XXX\VisuDevis.aspx.vb:ligne 560
>   Info Supplémentaire :Suppression RDV dans calendrier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Glen comments of 4/6/2020 is the right response
Here the summary

```
 Dim Appointment As New Appointment(service) With {
     .Subject = "MySubject",
     .Start = rdvEncours.DteInter,
     .Body = "MyBody",
     .Importance = Importance.High
 }
 Appointment.End = Appointment.Start.AddHours(1)
 Dim MaClef As String = getRandomString(256)
 Appointment.SetExtendedProperty(GetCustomKeyAppointment, MaClef)

 Appointment.Save(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, rdvEncours.Collaborateur.Mail))
 rdvEncours.ExchangeId = MaClef
 LesDatas.SaveChanges()
```

And, like u need to have one reference for your new custom key, in a module I've

```
 ' Get the GUID for the property set.
Private Const MyCustomKeySetId As String = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

Public Function GetCustomKeyAppointment() As ExtendedPropertyDefinition
    Return New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(New Guid(MyCustomKeySetId), "Mykey", MapiPropertyType.String)
End Function
```

And To find your appointment

```
 Public Function FindAppointment(Service As ExchangeService, UnikId As String) As Appointment
    Dim CalendarFolder As CalendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(Service, New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, ml), New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.TotalCount))

    ' Set the number of items to the smaller of the number of items in the Contacts folder Or 1000.
    Dim numItems As Integer = If(CalendarFolder.TotalCount < 1000, CalendarFolder.TotalCount, 1000)

    ' Instantiate the item view with the number of items to retrieve from the contacts folder.
    ' To keep the request smaller, send only the display name.
    Dim View As ItemView = New ItemView(numItems) With {.PropertySet = New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.End, AppointmentSchema.Start)}

    ' Create a searchfilter to check the subject of the tasks.
    Dim searchFilter As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(GetCustomKeyAppointment, UnikId)

    ' Retrieve the items in the Calendar folder with the properties you selected.
    Dim taskItems = Service.FindItems(New FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, ml), searchFilter, View)

    If taskItems.Count = 1 AndAlso TypeOf taskItems.Items(0) Is Appointment Then
        Return taskItems.Items(0)

    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ItemId then you can just Bind directly to the Calendar Item, the actual property isn't searchable so won't work in findItems. But just use

```
Appointment aptItem = Appointment.Bind(service, ItemId);
```

That said storing and binding to Itemid's can be problematic see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange as these itemId can change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. First : It's sur there is no modification between store and recall my appointment (around 10 seconds on a test account) Second I think The error  is more on the filter. Is it better to store too the changeId, and regenerate an itemId? I read all people store only uniqueId?

Comment: You won't be able to do a Search (Fitler) based on the uniqueId the Exchange Store doesn't allow this because its redundant (eg you have the Id so bind to it if you can't bind to it then that Id you have is no longer valid). If you want an Id you can search on I would suggest PidTagSearchKey https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsearchkey-canonical-property or create your own custom property and value.

Comment: Oh... I don't know that. Have U a simple sample about PidTagSearchKey or custom property. From storage to using in filter? Sorry to ask. But I don't have Exchange server to test. I need to deploy in real server et see if it's good, then If I can start from a good basis...

Comment: Have a look at the GOID example in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/48688e52-fabd-4015-b80a-f4cdc119e173/ews-how-to-fetch-a-particular-meeting-item?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment